# jq find value in object where key matches a regex

Tags: json, jq

In the JSON below, I need to find the value of the `id` key of every object where the value of `state` starts with "failed-"

```js
[
  {
    "id": "RA_kwDOGETrS84EmTf2",
    "state": "uploaded"
  },
  {
    "id": "RA_kwDOGETrS84EmTf6",
    "state": "failed-4325423"
  },
  {
    "id": "RA_kwDOGETrS84EmTf7",
    "state": "uploaded"
  }
]
```

I got as far as extracting just the matching values of `state`:

```
.[] | .state | select(startswith("failed-"))
```

How do I find the corresponding values of `id` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.[] | select(.state | startswith("failed-")).id
```

Will output:

```
"RA_kwDOGETrS84EmTf6"
```

Trick is to pass `state` in the [`select()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#select) to [`startswith()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#startswith), and then get `.id` of the result

---

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XIG4npKJyRu)

Answer (score 2):

```
.[] | select(.state | test("^failed")).id
```

is another way